# drag and drop using jquery ui sortable function need css to be changed

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

        <title>HTML</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="Sri Sahasra" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

        <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery_ui.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>



</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>





    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code what I need is when I am dragging the list items from one div to another div, the css property "border" has to be changed to "dashed border", I mean the list item which ever we move to another div that particular item border has to be changed. Can anybody please help me on this.

Comment: anybody there to answer this question...please help me...its urgent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the start and stop functions that are part of the sortable api. On start, change the border to dashed. On stop, change the border back to solid.

```
$(function() {
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    start: function(e,ui){
        ui.item.css('border-style', 'dashed');
    },
    stop: function(e,ui){
        ui.item.css('border-style', 'solid');
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

});

JSFiddle Example - http://jsfiddle.net/9YUxb/

I hope that helps.

To include border color you would return the css options as an object.

```
ui.item.css({
            'border-style': 'dashed',
            'border-color': '#ff0000'
        });
```

Comment: You would return the css options as an object and include any properties you want to change. Answer updated with example code. - Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9YUxb/8/

Comment: It's working me also, but I need border color only for latest dropped items only not for old or previous. Any idea. @theJooj